# How to measure mean in region of numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-slicing

Fairly new to using numpy, and I've got a piece of code where I've got a 2D array (image) where I want to calculate the mean and stddev of a square region with the array.  So +/- a certain delta in rows and cols around a specific point

Right now my code looks like this (for an arbitary region of 20 pixel size around (100, 100)):

```
r = 100
c = 100
r0 = r - 10
r1 = r + 10
c0 = c - 10
c1 = c + 10
mean = image[r0:r1, c0:c1].mean()
std = image[r0:r1, c0:c1].std()
```

### Question

Is there a more concise, or more numpy'ish/python'ish, way of calculating the slice to feed into mean() and std(), that doesn't take up so many lines?  (I know I could do it with numpy.where(), but the conditions then would take almost as many lines)

thanks!

Comment: BTW - I know I could do the +- variable ranges for the slices all in-line, instead of assigning variables over multiple lines, but I'm curious is there a more vector'ish/numpy'ish way of obtaining the slice - especially if it's not square etc.

Comment: There might be some obscure function, but I think from a maintainability perspective or performance perspective, there's nothing wrong with doing it all in-line and lining the indices on both lines up for readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I'm aware of, and I would be a little surprised if there were. What you have is very simple, so a special function for it wouldn't help much. My suggestion for readability would be to do the +/- inline to create a `region` array, then call the `mean` and `std` methods on that variable.

Also, in case you're wondering, the slicing that you've done there is pretty efficient, numpy shouldn't be creating a new array, just making a new view of the existing memory. Using something like `where` would make a new array.

Comment: Thanks for the info!  ...yeah, it is very simple, and fast/efficient too, but quite C-ish compared to numpy/vector'ish.  I was wondering if I was missing some numpy shortcut style way of doing it, but somewhat good to hear I'm not

Answer (score 0):

you can use these 2 tutorial:
[**numpy-mean**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html), 
[**numpy-std**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.std.html)